Different Type-C Cables and Connection Issues with Samsung Galaxy S24 Using ADB tool
I have two Type-C USB charging cables: Cable A and Cable B. Cable A is thicker than Cable B in appearance.
Devices used to test apps:
1.Samsung Galaxy S24
2.Google Pixel 7 Pro

Problem:
When using the 'adb devices 'command in the terminal, the Samsung Galaxy S24 device cannot be to detect (Already connected Cable B and Windows 10 computer), although this cable can connect to the Pixel 7 Pro device using ADB.
Cable A connects normally to both devices (adb).
I don't understand what the problem could be in this situation.
Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks!
Cable B also can connected other devices example for "MI9 pro, pixel 3a, Motorola E7 Power" ETC.
That charging cable successful to charged to 'Samsung Galaxy S24' when connected between win10 and Samsung.
Windows 10 is identify "Devices and Printers", and charging when connected:
Cable B : Samsung Galaxy S24 : Identify NO  : Changing YES
Cable B : Google Pixel 7 Pro : Identify YES : Changing YES
Cable A : Samsung Galaxy S24 : Identify YES : Changing YES
Cable A : Google Pixel 7 Pro : Identify YES : Changing YES


Could be that one cable is USB2 (no superspeed) and the other is USB3 and the Samsung no longer supports adb over USB 2...

@Robert Yes Bro, the adb was enabled on both devices. No more exclamation mark on device manage. I had tried to USBC cable3, in this situation even can't be charging, and 'adb devices' also  not response.

@Mokubai I tried to search "Samsung no longer supports adb over USB 2" someone may encounter same question with me. Will try to use the solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67902047/adb-is-not-recognizing-samsung-s21-when-connected-with-usb
